# C: Value being changed/overwritten

Tags: c

So this function (tmap_insert) is doing something curious. I call it in a loop, and for some reason, it overwrites the item->name (but not the item->val!) of all the previously added items in the tree whenever I add a new item, giving it the name of the most recent addition. I've posted my code here for you to look at--it's quite long but there isn't much I can do about that.

Also, I've included relevant structs, and the function which calls it in a loop.

```
int tmap_insert(TMAP_PTR t, char * name, double val){
    TMAP_PTR parent = malloc(sizeof(struct tmap_struct));
    TMAP_PTR new = malloc(sizeof(struct tmap_struct));
    NAME_VAL* temp = malloc(sizeof(NAME_VAL));
    temp->name = name;
    temp->value = val;        
    new->item = temp;    
    new->size = 1;
    new->height = 0;
    while (t != NULL)
    {
        t->size = t->size + 1;
        if (val > (t->item)->value)
        {
            parent = t;
            t = t->right;
        }
        else if (val < (t->item)->value)
        {
            parent = t;
            t = t->left;
        }
    }
    if (parent != NULL)
    {
        new->parent = parent;
        if (val > (parent->item)->value)
        {
            parent->right = new;
        }
        else if (val < (parent->item)->value)
        {
            parent->left = new;
        }
    }
    TMAP_PTR unbalanced = malloc(sizeof(struct tmap_struct));
    unbalanced = NULL;
    TMAP_PTR iterator = malloc(sizeof(struct tmap_struct));
    iterator = new->parent;
    while (iterator != NULL)
    {
        if (iterator->left != NULL && iterator->right != NULL)
        {
            if ((iterator->left)->size > (2*((iterator->right)->size) + 1) || (iterator->right)->size > (2*((iterator->left)->size) + 1))
            {
                unbalanced = iterator;
            }
            if ((iterator->left)->height > (iterator->right)->height)
            {
                iterator->height = (iterator->left)->height + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                iterator->height = (iterator->right)->height + 1;
            }
        }
        else if (iterator->left != NULL)
        {
            if ((iterator->left)->size > 1)
            {
                unbalanced = iterator;
            }
            iterator->height = (iterator->left)->height + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            if ((iterator->right)->size > 1)
            {
                unbalanced = iterator;
            }
            iterator->height = (iterator->right)->height + 1;
        }        
        iterator = iterator->parent;
    }
    if (unbalanced != NULL)
    {
        NAME_VAL **arr = malloc(unbalanced->size * sizeof(NAME_VAL*));
        int i;        
        for (i = 0; i < unbalanced->size; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = malloc(sizeof(NAME_VAL));
        }
        int *index = malloc(sizeof(int));
        *index = 0;        
        arr = make_arr(unbalanced, arr, index);

        int pos = ((unbalanced->size) / 2);

        TMAP_PTR head = malloc(sizeof(struct tmap_struct));
        head->size = 1;
        head->height = 0;
        head->item = arr[pos];
        rebalance(arr, 0, pos-1, head);
        rebalance(arr, pos+1, unbalanced->size, head);
        unbalanced->parent = head->parent;
        if ((unbalanced->parent)->right == unbalanced)
        {
            (unbalanced->parent)->right = head;
        }
        else
        {
            (unbalanced->parent)->left = head;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}


TMAP_PTR tmap_create(char *fname){
    printf("%s", fname);
    fflush(stdout);
    FILE *src;
    src = fopen(fname, "r");
    if (src == NULL)
    {
        printf("File could not open!\n");
        return;
    }
    double value;
    char name[20];

    TMAP_PTR head = malloc(sizeof(struct tmap_struct));
    head->size = 1;
    head->height = 0;

    fscanf(src, "%s", name);
    fscanf(src, "%lf", &value);
    head->item = malloc(sizeof(NAME_VAL));
    (head->item)->value = value;
    (head->item)->name = name;

    while (fscanf(src, "%s %lf", name, &value) == 2)
    {
        printf("%s", name);
        fflush(stdout);
        tmap_insert(head, name, value);
    }
    return head;

}

struct tmap_struct{
    TMAP_PTR parent;
    TMAP_PTR left;
    TMAP_PTR right;
    int height;
    int size;
    NAME_VAL* item;
};

typedef struct name_val {
    char *name;
    double value;
}NAME_VAL;
```

Comment: `char name[20];` You are letting all `thing->name` members point to the same array. You need to allocate space and copy the names.

Comment: Specifically, `temp->name = name` in the insert proc. Thats the wrong way to do that. And a side note, there are **eleven** `malloc()` calls in this code, and not one single `free()` *anywhere*. I trust you'll take care of that.

Comment: I will most definitely take care of that, but I need to get the code functioning before I worry too much about memory leaks. I'm having trouble finding the bug still. Is it temp->name = name specifically? I added temp->name = malloc(20) and then temp->name = name, but that didn't seem to help.

Comment: That would be what is called a *memory leak* (your comment code). Are you familiar with the functions `strlen()` and `strcpy()`. If on a POSIX system, are you familiar with the function `strdup()` (which I don't really recommend, but it is none-the-less usually available).

Comment: I am familiar with `strlen()` and `strcpy()`. I've brushed up with `strdup()` but I don't use it that much... let me try that.

I changed the assignment to `temp->name = malloc(20); strcpy(temp->name, name);` and still no fix.

Comment: `TMAP_PTR unbalanced = malloc(sizeof(struct tmap_struct));
    unbalanced = NULL;
    TMAP_PTR iterator = malloc(sizeof(struct tmap_struct));
    iterator = new->parent;` these are two memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

In `tmap_create(char *fname)` you allocate an array of char for name, then in each step of your loop you read in it the new value of name, and pass it to the function tmap_insert, where you create a new node and store in it the pointer to the char array. So, obviously, all the nodes of the tree point to the same char array, and when you store in it a new string, all the nodes see the new value. The solution is to allocate a new char array for each name you have to store. 
You should replace the while loop in tmap_create() with:

```
char* name = malloc(20*sizeof(char));
while (fscanf(src, "%s %lf", name, &value) == 2)
    {
        printf("%s", name);
        fflush(stdout);
        tmap_insert(head, name, value);
        name = malloc(20*sizeof(char));
    }
```